# How to scale database being used for matching service in temporal workflow

Tags: temporal-workflow

If we use activity id as sharding key for database matching service used, reading by queue name will query all sharding tables, which is expensive. How do we set up database for matching service?

Answer (score 0):

Matching service stores tasks in [task_queues](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/blob/2c40ed5bf4128367f894accae981491f6b01bc7b/schema/postgresql/v96/temporal/schema.sql#L82) table:

```
CREATE TABLE task_queues
  range_hash BIGINT NOT NULL,
  task_queue_id BYTEA NOT NULL,
  --
  range_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  data BYTEA NOT NULL,
  data_encoding VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (range_hash, task_queue_id)
);
```

Its primary key is (`range_hash`, `task_queue_id`) pair. So you must shard by either `range_hash` or (`range_hash`, `task_queue_id`) pair. Any other sharding strategy is not going to work. Sharding a single task queue id doesn't make sense as it by design has very limited throughput. A single task queue is broken into multiple partitions each with its own id.

`range_hash` is a [hash](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/blob/bb7b984ef5e2866037cd47e6d377a412780ecbb3/common/persistence/sql/task.go#L494-L494) of a particular TaskQueue/Task given a Namespace, TaskQueueName and TaskQueueType.

`range_id` is absolutely unrelated to the `range_hash`. It is used to ensure that only a single matching node can operate on this particular task queue partition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can i ask what does range_hash, range_id mean here?

Comment: Added info to the answer